# Get every 100th "Like" for Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-opengraph

We would like to reward every 100th **Like** of a Facebook page. I've seen other pages doing this, but all of them seem to be operating manually.

Is it possible to get this information using the current Facebook APIs? The fan count could probably be polled using a cronjob, but if too many people like the page between polls the count may go from 199 to 201 and we won't know who was the 200th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get data about who likes your page via the Facebook API, and probably never will be able to.